# Get Table ID From Another Page Using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application and i want to post data to table using AJAX. in `Table.cshtml` page my markup is

```
    <table id="myTable">
         <tr>
             <th>User Name</th>
             <th>Email</th>
             <th>Password</th>
         </tr> 
    </table>
```

and in `Index.cshtml` i have a form which i want to post it's contents to the table. but the problem is i don't know how to retrieve id of table inside this page. here's my ajax code

```
<script>
        var userName = $("#UserName").val();
        var email = $("#Email").val();
        var password = $("#Password").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ UserName: userName, Email: email, Password: password }),
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function(result) {
                $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + <---- How i get this id from Table.cshtml Page?
                    result.UserName +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    result.Email +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    result.Password +
                    "</td></tr>");
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: what id value do you mean? you don't have an id field in your table!

Comment: @AmirJelo yes i have written on Tables page's markup

Answer (score 0):

`id` is an attribute, so you can get it like:

```
$("#myTable").attr('id')
```

So your code should look like this:

```
success: function(result) {
                $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + $("#myTable").attr('id') +
                    result.UserName +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    result.Email +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    result.Password +
                    "</td></tr>");
            }
```